# Lua Problems with Arguments

Tags: lua, type-conversion, minecraft

What's wrong with this lua code, my argument is never converted to a number or recognized as a number no matter what I type?

I tried "distance = tonumber(arg[0]) or 0" as well.

```
--Args

local args = {...}

--Variables

local distance = 0
if #args > 0 and type(args[0])=="string" then args[0] = tonumber(args[0]) end
if #args > 0 and type(args[0])=="number" then distance = args[0] end
print("Distance: "..distance)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua uses 1-based indices for its arrays. `args[0]` is `nil`, and therefore has the type `"nil"`.

By the way, this condition is entirely unnecessary. `tonumber` will check to see if its argument is a number and simply return it if needed. It will return `nil` if the argument cannot be converted to a number. So just use:

```
distance = tonumber(args[1])
```

You don't even need to check the length of `args`; if no arguments were provided, it will be `nil`, and `tonumber` will return `nil`. Thus, just check to see if `distance` is `nil`.